# Problem autostarting pigpiod

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+, pigpio, systemd

On my Pi3B+ I had pigpiod configured to run on boot and I can successfully run compiled c programs; specifically DHTXXD.c which contains:-

```
/*
DHTXXD.c
2016-02-16
Public Domain
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <pigpiod_if2.h>
```

However when I try to run `pigs hwver` I get an error "socket connect failed" even though `systemctl status pigpiod` shows it is running and port 8888 is open.

Indeed any `pigs` command failed.

I disabled and reenabled `pigpiod` with `sudo systemctl enable pigpiod` which responded:-

```
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/pigpiod.service → /lib/systemd/system/pigpiod.service.
```

When I disable `pigpiod` on boot then `DHTXXD` fails.

If I manually enable with `sudo pigpiod` then both work.

With `pigpiod` manually started

```
$ sudo systemctl status pigpiod
● pigpiod.service - Daemon required to control GPIO pins via pigpio
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/pigpiod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

With `pigpiod` automatically started

```
$ sudo systemctl status pigpiod
● pigpiod.service - Daemon required to control GPIO pins via pigpio
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/pigpiod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-12-13 12:18:39 AEDT; 35s ago
  Process: 347 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pigpiod -l (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 371 (pigpiod)
   CGroup: /system.slice/pigpiod.service
           └─371 /usr/bin/pigpiod -l
```

Anyone have any idea to make reliable autostart?

Comment: Sorry if this sounds flippant but it does look as though it has something to do with the `systemd` setup - I use the older (non-standard these days) sysV `init` to run my own daemon from that setup's `/erc/rc.local` that spawns a separate `pigpiod` thread - and from what I recall of @joan 's pigpio library it used to (I am not sure that it used the same mechanism nowadays) check that there is only one instance running by looking for a `/run/pigpiod.pid` file - but if it crashed previously that file might still be around and be preventing a new instance from starting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this problem, I discovered **WHY**
- the `/lib/systemd/system/pigpiod.service` was set to **Disable remote socket interface**!

How to **fix** it - either fix the faulty `pigpiod.service` script -
remove the `-l` switch in

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pigpiod -l
```

**OR** Run `raspi-config` and `Interfacing Options` will allow you to enable or disable remote connection to GPIO server. The actual unit script is fine and does not need to be changed.

See also https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/104441/8697

Answer (score 0):

This problem will be fixed in pigpiod version 77.

Workaround is bind the demon an the local ip:

/lib/systemd/system/pigpiod.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pigpiod -l -n 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

My Pi came without pigpio installed for some odd reason
(64 bit Lite OS)

**sudo apt-get install pigpio**
*once installed*
**sudo systemctl enable pigpiod** (not a typo)
**sudo systemctl start pigpiod**